# Caught KeyError while rendering: 'opts' in admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

I start to make custom admin view, with custom template. I created template, extended by built-in change_form.html template, form, view and url. I changed `{% block form_top %}` of orig template in my extended version, passing my form in there. When I view the url of my page, I got an error:

> Caught KeyError while rendering: 'opts' in admin interface.

This happens in line 60 of template in `{% submit_row %}` template tag. Full traceback in there http://dpaste.com/hold/612843/. What is there is not enough? Where to look the lack?

#### Edit:

```
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block form_top %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
{% endblock %}
```

#### Edit:

```
def order_cats(request):
    form = OrderCats()
    return direct_to_template(request, 'admin/shivaapp/order_cats.djhtml',
                          {'form': form})
```

Comment: Something strange here, the request url in the dpased traceback (`http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/shivaapp/order_cats`) suggests the change_list page, not the change_form. Some mix up ?

Comment: Noup. Added template code to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake was that I needed to override `{% block content %}`, but not `{% block form_top %}`.

Answer (score 0):

mkriheli is correct, there is something odd with this url being rendered as a change_form rather than a change_list. Apparently you customised the admin view in `shivaapp/admin_views.py`, but did so incorrectly.

Comment: I see you right, I'm not did it, I just create very simple view passed form to template. I see this is not enough. Edited my question.